# Quasar v-money always setting to $0,00

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I created a simple component

```
<template>
  <div class="MoneyInput1 col-grow block">
    <div class="block text-left q-py-md">
      <label class="label-1">
        {{ props.jLabel }}
      </label>
    </div>
    <q-field
      :model-value="props.modelValue"
      borderless
      @update:modelValue="e => {$emit('update:modelValue', e)}"
    >
      {{ props.modelValue }}
      <template v-slot:control="{ id, emitValue }">
        <input
          :id="id"
          v-money="moneyFormatForDirective"
          class="input-1 money-input basis-medium"
          model-value="modelValue"
          @change.self="e => emitValue(e.target.value)"
        >
      </template>
    </q-field>
  </div>
</template>
```

with the moneyFormat as the following

```
const moneyFormatForDirective = {
  decimal: ',',
  thousands: '.',
  prefix: '$ ',
  precision: 2,
  masked: false,
};
```

The problem is that it triggers two updates, one setting the value from the parent, which is sent with v-model. The following sets it to $0,00

I saw that it could be possible to be done with v-model.lazy, but with the @change I have no idea.